# Missing Secure Attribute in Session Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-config

Hi I am working on the asp.net website. I am using session to keep user logged in. The site was working perfectly until I had to add

`<system.web>
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" /> 
</system.web>`

in web.config.

As the auditor reported vulnerability "Missing Secure Attribute in Session Cookie". The site is just not retrieving the session being set after adding above code in web.config.

I am getting error:

```
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either 
in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that 
System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the 
<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
```

I tried adding `enableSessionState` to my pages tag in web.config

`<pages enableViewStateMac="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableEventValidation="true" enableSessionState="true">`

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check that the ASP.NET Session State Manager Service service is running?

Comment: I am running the website locally. I have not published the website on IIS. Also it works if I remove <httpCookies> tag from web.config